# developer ID is not visible in approvals and checks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Azure DevOps: I have a yml pipeline, I have created an environment called Prod. And Added Approvals and checks to the environment and added myID as an approver. My Pipeline is working 100% ok.
But the problem is I wanted to add some other user ID (Lead Developer) as an approver. But when I try to select the userID who can approve the pipeline, I can see my ID and my manager's ID, But I don't see Lead Developers ID. Please let me know how can I ensure that my Lead Developer ID is visible in the approver's list.

[Approvers in Approvals and checks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFYyc.png)

Project Settings > Teams > ProjectName_Team  > here I can see all IDS (myself, my manager, and all the developers including the Developer Lead), but why these IDs are not visible in list when i am trying to add developer lead as an approver. Instead, i can see my ID and my manager ID only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Settings >Permissions > Groups > Create a new Group (example : prd-approvers) and add users to this group.

Now Pipelines > Environments > prd > Approvals and checks from 3 dots in right corner> Approvers > Add Group (prd-approvers).

I have created 4 environments:

1. prd
2. prd-post
3. tst
4. tst-post
   and for every environment , I created a separate group.